# how to delegate on specific postion(row, col) in PyQt QTreeView

Tags: delegates, icons, pyqt, qtreeview

my purpose is to **display an different icon** in treeview list **when a specific postion(row, column) match a value. eg: (row, 2) is dir or file, will diplay different icon**. because this is not used in local filesystem, QDir or Qfilesystem model not suite for this.

i know a bit on MVC that controller display in view, make model as data interface api.  but i do not how to make it works on specific position(row ,col) as my expect.

i have tried to add args in ImageDelegate(like pass icon file name to it), but failed maybe due to its parent Class not accept more args.
hope someone can give me some light.

```
class ImageDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
        #self.icon =icon
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        #painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QColor(191,222,185))
        # path = "path\to\my\image.jpg"
        path = "icon1.png"
        image = QtGui.QImage(str(path))
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        pixmap.scaled(16, 16, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        painter.drawPixmap(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y(),  pixmap)
```

and i can use this delegate in my view. but it will change all line in specific column.

```
def init_remotetreeview(self):
    self.model = myModel(self.remote_Treeview)

    for therow in range(self.model.rowCount(QModelIndex())) :
        print self.model.data(self.model.index(therow, 2, QtCore.QModelIndex()),Qt.DisplayRole).toString()   # i do check the value will used to load correct icon.
    self.remote_Treeview.setItemDelegate(ImageDelegate(self))  # this change all lines
    self.remote_Treeview.setModel(self.model)
```

Comment: If I understand you right, you just want the icons in colunm 4 (a single icon per row I assume?) to depend on the contents of column 2? If that is the case you don't need a delegate at all. You just need to change the way your model behaves. Could your provide some code that shows the implementation of your model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, your have `some light` in your code, isn't it ? (Just kidding.)

Your have right way to use `QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate`. I have reference how to implement it (But, C++ only). ['Star Delegate Example'](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/itemviews-stardelegate.html), ['QItemDelegate Class Reference C++'](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html) and ['QItemDelegate Class Reference PyQt4'](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qitemdelegate.html);

**Keyword** : Your have to implement `paint` draw your element what your want (I think this is your want.)

Little example, Hope is help;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from functools import partial

class QCustomDelegate (QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    signalNewPath = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def createEditor (self, parentQWidget, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 0:
            editorQWidget = QtGui.QPushButton(parentQWidget)
            editorQWidget.released.connect(partial(self.requestNewPath, indexQModelIndex))
            return editorQWidget            
        else:
            return QtGui.QItemDelegate.createEditor(self, parentQWidget, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex)

    def setEditorData (self, editorQWidget, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 0:
            textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
            editorQWidget.setText(textQString)
        else:
            QtGui.QItemDelegate.setEditorData(self, editorQWidget, indexQModelIndex)

    def setModelData (self, editorQWidget, modelQAbstractItemModel, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 0:
            textQString = editorQWidget.text()
            modelQAbstractItemModel.setData(indexQModelIndex, textQString, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        else:
            QtGui.QItemDelegate.setModelData(self, editorQWidget, modelQAbstractItemModel, indexQModelIndex)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editorQWidget, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 0:
            editorQWidget.setGeometry(optionQStyleOptionViewItem.rect)
        else:
            QtGui.QItemDelegate.updateEditorGeometry(self, editorQWidget, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex)

    def requestNewPath (self, indexQModelIndex):
        self.signalNewPath.emit(indexQModelIndex)

    def paint (self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 0:
            textQString = indexQModelIndex.model().data(indexQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
            painterQPainter.drawPixmap (
                optionQStyleOptionViewItem.rect.x(),
                optionQStyleOptionViewItem.rect.y(),
                QtGui.QPixmap(textQString).scaled(180, 180, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        else:
            QtGui.QItemDelegate.paint(self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex)

class QCustomTreeWidget (QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomTreeWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setColumnCount(1)
        myQCustomDelegate = QCustomDelegate()
        self.setItemDelegate(myQCustomDelegate)
        myQCustomDelegate.signalNewPath.connect(self.getNewPath)

    def addMenu (self, path, parentQTreeWidgetItem = None):
        if parentQTreeWidgetItem == None:
            parentQTreeWidgetItem = self.invisibleRootItem()
        currentQTreeWidgetItem = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(parentQTreeWidgetItem)
        currentQTreeWidgetItem.setData(0, QtCore.Qt.EditRole, path)
        currentQTreeWidgetItem.setFlags(currentQTreeWidgetItem.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        for i in range(self.columnCount()):
            currentQSize = currentQTreeWidgetItem.sizeHint(i)
            currentQTreeWidgetItem.setSizeHint(i, QtCore.QSize(currentQSize.width(), currentQSize.height() + 200))

    def getNewPath (self, indexQModelIndex):
        currentQTreeWidgetItem = self.itemFromIndex(indexQModelIndex)
        pathQStringList = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()
        if pathQStringList.count() > 0:
            textQString = pathQStringList.first()
            currentQTreeWidgetItem.setData(indexQModelIndex.column(), QtCore.Qt.EditRole, textQString)
            print textQString

class QCustomQWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.myQCustomTreeWidget = QCustomTreeWidget(self)
        self.allQHBoxLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.myQCustomTreeWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.allQHBoxLayout)
        self.myQCustomTreeWidget.addMenu(r'''C:\Users\Kitsune Meyoko\Desktop\twitter01.jpg''')
        self.myQCustomTreeWidget.addMenu(r'''C:\Users\Kitsune Meyoko\Desktop\twitter02.jpg''')
        self.myQCustomTreeWidget.addMenu(r'''C:\Users\Kitsune Meyoko\Desktop\twitter04.jpg''')
        self.myQCustomTreeWidget.addMenu(r'''C:\Users\Kitsune Meyoko\Desktop\twitter05.jpg''')

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
myQCustomQWidget = QCustomQWidget()
myQCustomQWidget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note: In same way to implement `QTreeView`, but different is set values only.

If your want to show image by path in some index (In this case : 2nd). Your can find it by using [QModelIndex QAbstractItemModel.index (self, int row, int column, QModelIndex parent = QModelIndex())](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemmodel.html#index), And do want your want.

Example;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class QCustomDelegate (QtGui.QItemDelegate):
    def paint (self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex):
        column = indexQModelIndex.column()
        if column == 3:
            currentQAbstractItemModel = indexQModelIndex.model()
            iconQModelIndex           = currentQAbstractItemModel.index(indexQModelIndex.row(), 1, indexQModelIndex.parent())
            pathQString               = currentQAbstractItemModel.data(iconQModelIndex, QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString()
            iconQPixmap               = QtGui.QPixmap(pathQString)
            if not iconQPixmap.isNull():
                painterQPainter.drawPixmap (
                    optionQStyleOptionViewItem.rect.x(),
                    optionQStyleOptionViewItem.rect.y(),
                    iconQPixmap.scaled(20, 20, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        else:
            QtGui.QItemDelegate.paint(self, painterQPainter, optionQStyleOptionViewItem, indexQModelIndex)

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication([])

myQTreeView = QtGui.QTreeView()
headerQStandardItemModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
headerQStandardItemModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([''] * 4)
myQTreeView.setModel(headerQStandardItemModel)
# Set delegate
myQCustomDelegate = QCustomDelegate()
myQTreeView.setItemDelegate(myQCustomDelegate)
# Append data row 1
row1QStandardItem = QtGui.QStandardItem('ROW 1')
row1QStandardItem.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem(''), QtGui.QStandardItem('1.jpg'), QtGui.QStandardItem(''), QtGui.QStandardItem('')])
headerQStandardItemModel.appendRow(row1QStandardItem)
# Append data row 2
row2QStandardItem = QtGui.QStandardItem('ROW 2')
row2QStandardItem.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem(''), QtGui.QStandardItem('2.png'), QtGui.QStandardItem(''), QtGui.QStandardItem('')])
headerQStandardItemModel.appendRow(row2QStandardItem)
myQTreeView.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

**experimental result:**

[image]

Note: I have image 1.jpg, 2.png.

Comment: yes, i know how to use basic setDelegateForColumn, my problem is that i have 4 column display in TreeView, the 4th column display the icon, but in fact i need display different icon basic on the 2rd column value.  treewidget maybe a bit easy to put the icon, i am stuck on the TreeView

Comment: OK, sorry for mistake your question. Please read my last answer.

Comment: thanks， QstandarditemModel, should be easy and coorect way to do this. thanks to your sample.